# What are the 7 spirits of God in Revelation 4:5 and 5:6? 7 lampstands are 7 spirits and 7 horns & 7 eyes are the 7 Spirits of God. Which are they?

Tags: spirits

In Rev 4:6 and 5:6 it says these are the 7 spirits of God.  In Rev 4:5 it states that the lampstands are the 7 Spirits of God then in 5:6 it states that the 7 horns and the 7 eyes are the 7 Spirits of God.

> Rev 4:5 - From the throne came flashes of lightning, rumblings and
> peals of thunder. In front of the throne, seven lamps were blazing.
> These are the seven spirits a of God.

> Rev 5:6 - Then I saw a Lamb, looking as if it had been slain, standing
> at the center of the throne, encircled by the four living creatures
> and the elders. The Lamb had seven horns and seven eyes, which are the
> seven spirits  of God sent out into all the earth.

But what do each of the seven spirits represent? Like the fruit of the spirit is joy, peace, etc?

Comment: Hello Kathleen.  Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your excellent question.  Please do not forget to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Oooo this is a lekker question I’m enjoying Dottard’s answer and will enjoy writing one too! (Not with Dottard’s level of scriptural facility to be sure, but I will try in my small way.)

Comment: See Isaiah 11:2-3 and [amesha spenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amesha_Spenta).

Comment: In Rev 5:6 it says that God's seven spirits are "sent out into all the earth". Could the fact that the number of God's Spirits and the number of the earth's regions are the same just be a coincident? North America, South America, Europe, Africa, West Asia, East Asia, and Oceania.

Answer (score 4):

First, let us be clear about the different words associated with fire in the book of Revelation.

**1. λαμπάς** (lampas = "torch", "lamp", "lantern") only occurs twice in:

- Rev 4:5 - From the throne came flashes of lightning, and rumblings, and peals of thunder. Before the throne burned seven **torches** of fire. These are the seven Spirits of God.
- Rev 8:10 - Then the third angel sounded his trumpet, and a great star burning like a **torch** fell from heaven and landed on a third of the rivers and on the springs of water.

Note that in Rev 4:5, the torch is used to symbolize the Spirit and in Rev 8:10 it symbolizes a false spirit.

**2. λυχνία** (luchna = "lamp-stand") and occurs seven times in:

- Rev 1:12, 13 - Then I turned to see the voice that was speaking with me. And having turned, I saw seven golden **lampstands**, and among the **lampstands** was One like the Son of Man,f dressed in a long robe, with a golden sash around His chest.
- Rev 1:20 - This is the mystery of the seven stars you saw in My right hand and of the seven golden **lampstands**: The seven stars are the angels of the seven churches, and the seven **lampstands** are the seven churches.
- Rev 2:1 - “To the angel of the church in Ephesus write: These are the words of Him who holds the seven stars in His right hand and walks among the seven golden **lampstands**.
- Rev 2:5 - Therefore, keep in mind how far you have fallen. Repent and perform the deeds you did at first. But if you do not repent, I will come to you and remove your **lampstand** from its place.
- Rev 11:4 - These witnesses are the two olive trees and the two **lampstands** that stand before the Lord of the earth.

Note that a lampstand always represents a church in some sense, either one of the seven churches or other church.  This symbol is a clear reference to the Menorah in the ancient Temple/sanctuary and Jesus' own comment that He (Jesus) was the light of the world, John 1:4, 8:12

**"*Seven Spirits*"**

The phrase "Seven Spirits" occurs a number of times in the book of Revelations as follows:

- Rev 1:4 - John, To the seven churches in the province of Asia: Grace and peace to you from Him who is and was and is to come, and from the **seven Spirits before His throne**
- Rev 3:1 - “To the angel of the church in Sardis write: These are the words of the One who holds the **seven Spirits of God** and the seven stars. I know your deeds; you have a reputation for being alive, yet you are dead.
- Rev 4:5 - From the throne came flashes of lightning, and rumblings, and peals of thunder. Before the throne burned seven torches of fire. These are the **seven Spirits of God**.
- Rev 5:6 - Then I saw a Lamb who appeared to have been slain, standing in the center of the throne, encircled by the four living creatures and the elders. The Lamb had seven horns and seven eyes, which represent the **seven Spirits of God** sent out into all the earth.

[For completeness only, note the same phrase also occurs in Matt 12:45 & Luke 11:26 in one of Jesus' parables concerning evil spirits inhabiting a person.]

Note that these descriptions give us valuable information:

- the seven Spirits are "of God"
- the seven Spirits send greetings of grace and peace to the seven churches
- the seven Spirits are held in the hand of Jesus
- the seven Spirits are also called the eyes of Jesus
- the seven Spirits are associated with and near the throne of God
- the seven Spirits are likened to burning torches

[There also appears to be a counterfeit "torch" that falls from heaven in Rev 8:10 (compare Luke 10:18, Rev 9:1, 12:4, Isa 14:12, etc)]

All these descriptions of the seven Spirits appears to be an allusion to the prophecies of Zechariah:

- Zech 3:9 - See the stone I have set before Joshua; on that one stone are seven eyes. Behold, I will engrave on it an inscription, declares the LORD of Hosts, and I will remove the iniquity of this land in a single day.
- Zech 4:2 - “What do you see?” he asked. “I see a solid gold lampstand,” I replied, “with a bowl at the top and seven lamps on it, with seven spouts to the lamps.
- Zech 4:6 - So he said to me, “This is the word of the LORD to Zerubbabel: Not by might nor by power, but by My Spirit, says the LORD of Hosts.
- Zech 4:10 - For who has despised the day of small things? But these seven eyes of the LORD, which scan the whole earth, will rejoice when they see the plumb line in the hand of Zerubbabel.”

Thus, as many have already observed such as Ellicott in his remarks about Rev 1:4 -

> The context makes it impossible to admit any other meaning than that
> the greeting which comes from the Father and the Son comes also from
> the Holy Spirit sevenfold in His operations, whose gifts are diffused
> among all the churches, and who divides to every man severally as He
> will. ... This unity in diversity is the thought St. Paul seems
> anxious to keep before the minds of the Corinthians, lest their gifts
> should become the source of division. All work that one and self-same
> spirit (1 Cor 12:11).

Some have also suggested that the "seven Spirits" might be better rendered "seven-fold Spirit" (eg, NIV footnote and others) and thus, the seven functions of the Holy Spirit; but I would not be anxious to press this too far nor too strongly - it is mentioned for completeness only.  See appendix below.

The extremely close association of the Spirit with Jesus and the Revelation of Jesus is discussed in John 16:13, 14 - The Spirit reveals Jesus to us.

**APPENDIX - Work of the Holy Spirit**

Jesus bequeathed the Gift of the Holy Spirit (John 20:22, Acts 1:8, 2:1-4) to His church for several reasons:

1. To produce the fruit of the Spirit (Gal 5:22 & 23, see especially v24-26) and so to sanctify (make distinct) the church members.
2. The above changed life is to be a distinguishing sign or seal of God’s ownership of our lives and a guarantee of better things to come (Eph 1:13, 4:30) and the "seal of God".
3. To provide specific guidance for the church (John 16:7-12, 14:17, 15:26 –  namely

- Convict of sin
- Instruct in Righteous (= right doing)
- Convict of judgement to come

4. To build up the church with spiritual (supernatural) gifts and abilities, 1 Cor 12:7, 14:12, and to influence/teach others John 7:37-39.  See Rom 12:6-8, 1 Cor 12:8-10, 28-30, Eph 4:11, 1 Peter 4:10, 11, 1 Tim 4:14, Ex 35:30-33, etc.
5. To strengthen the members in their daily walk to live the Christian ideals, Eph 3:16, 17, Heb 2:4, and maintain unity in the Christian community (Eph 4:3-6).  The Christian must be born of the Spirit (John 3:5) by receiving the gift of the Spirit (Acts 2:38) and walk by the Spirit (Gal 5:25, John 6:63, Phil 3:3, John 4:24).  In fact the whole life of Christian is to put aside the “psychical” mind and live by the Spirit (1 Cor 2:14, 1 Cor 15:44-46, Gal 5:17, Jude 19, John 6:63, 1 Peter 3:18).  In short, the Holy Spirit is the only way we can know God, 1 Cor 2:10, 11, 14, John 16:13.
6. To teach the church more of the character and work of Jesus and thus, imitate Jesus, John 7:38, 39, 15:26, 16:12-15, Rom 8:4, 11, Eph 3:17, 18, 4:3-6, 1 Thess 1:6, 4:8, 1 Cor 2:14.
7. The Holy Spirit inspired the prophets to write Scripture, and explains such spiritual truths to us.  John 14:16, 17, 15:26, 1 Cor 2:6-16, Eph 1:17-19, 2 Peter 1:21, 2 Tim 3:15, 16, 1 Thess 1:5, Heb 9:8, 1 Peter 1:12, Ps 119:18.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd just like to add something onto the previous answer as I think you're onto something when you suggest that the seven spirits in Revelation represent specific gifts or virtues. While a lot of the imagery is drawn from Zechariah, as the other answer noted, the idea of seven spirits is probably drawn from Isaiah 11:2-3. In the Masoretic Text (Hebrew) from which most English Bible versions are translated, only six spirits are mentioned:

"The spirit of the Lord shall rest upon him: a spirit of wisdom (1) and of understanding (2), A spirit of counsel (3) and of strength (4), a spirit of knowledge (5) and of fear of the Lord (6), and his delight shall be the fear of the Lord." (Isaiah 11:2-3 NABRE)

In the Greek Septuagint, however, there are seven spirits mentioned:

"And the spirit of God shall rest on him,
the spirit of wisdom (1) and understanding (2), the spirit of counsel (3) and might (4), the spirit of knowledge (5) and godliness (6). The spirit of the fear of God (7) will fill him." (Isaiah 11:2-3 New English Translation of the Septuagint)

The Septuagint (most of which dates to the 3rd century B.C.) was the main Bible used by the early church outside the Holy Land - especially in Greek speaking regions like Patmos (where John saw the visions recorded in Revelation) and Asia (where the seven churches were to which the book was addressed). Hence we can be certain that John was familiar with Isaiah 11 in the Septuagint and thus with the seven spirits mentioned there.

The seven spirits are thus a way of referring to the Spirit of God, or what is usually called the Holy Spirit in the New Testament, but this unique terminology draws attention to the sevenfold manifestation of the Spirit that Isaiah (Septuagint version) foretold would be on the Messiah and thus also on the Messianic community that he established.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Comment: +1. Isaiah 11 on The Lord’s Prayer //  
Our Father who art in heaven hallowed be thy name (Fear of God) // Thy kingdom come, thy will be done on earth as it is in heaven (Might) // Give as this day our daily bread. (Knowledge) // Forgive us our trespasses (Understanding) // As we forgive those who trespass against us (Godliness) // Lead us not into temptation (Counsel) // Deliver us from evil (Wisdom).

Answer (score 1):

To answer part of the question, Chuck Missler has this insight if I understood him correctly: Could the seven lampstands in Revelation 1:20, which is the church filled with the Holy Spirit, be the church as well in Revelation 4:5 now seen as the seven fiery torches, no longer as a lampstand since the believers are no longer needing the physical lamp stand as their representation, being free of their physical bodies, being Raptured in God's presence? To be absent from the body is to be present with the Lord, 2 Corinthians 5:8-10.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Missler (died 2018) started an online ministry, Koinonia House, and became known as a prominent Christian Zionist. Why should his views be worthy of our considerstion?

Answer (score 0):

As it has been revealed to me, the seven spirits of God are:

▪️Love

▪️Truth

▪️Justice

▪️Peace

▪️Hope

▪️Faith

▪️Modesty

After receiving this revelation I observed in scripture how Christ’s crucifixion is shaped and defined by the LORD being denied each of these.

▪️The father is Love, and the father forsook Yeshua on the cross.

▪️Yeshua was denied the benefit of Truth by Pilate who asked “what is truth?”. He regarded political power more than truth, which led to the messiah’s death.

▪️Yeshua was denied Justice on account of His innocence of any wrongdoing.

▪️Yeshua was denied peace as he anguished in the garden of Gethsemane.

▪️Yeshua denied himself of any hope of being relieved of His gruesome death. “Not my will but thy will be done.”

▪️Yeshua was denied the comfort of faith and thus filled with faith’s opposite, fear.

▪️Yeshua was denied modesty (dignity) as He was crucified naked, labeled a criminal, mocked, despised and rejected.

Comment: There are some profound points listed about what the Son of Man was denied at his crucifixion - thanks for sharing those. However, on this Biblical Hermeneutics site the requirement is to examine the verses in question and see what the biblical text says by way an answer. Personal opinions (or revelations) are not what can help others dig out the deeper meanings. Can you show anything from the bits in Revelation cited that could confirm your claims?

Comment: I understand. The scripture never explicitly identifies each of the seven spirits of God. Thankfully God by His spirit gives revelation, which is the truth about the pages of scripture that’s not written on the pages. Scripture is designed with gaps that require those who study it to seek Him for complete understanding. Acts 17:27 “God did this so that they would seek him and perhaps reach out for him and find him, though he is not far from any one of us.”. This question can only be answered by revelation of Truth which is above what is written. My answer is inspired by the author of scripture

Comment: I appreciate that; it’s just that this site requires some substantiation for any claims made, otherwise everyone will just pitch in with their own opinions, many of which never were inspired by the Spirit of Truth! After all, this site avoids claiming to be a ‘Christian’ site, so it’s not out to promote Christianity or the Bible. The ‘Tour’ link at the bottom l.h.s. shows how this site is different to other sites.

Comment: What I have to offer has repeatedly been flagged, edited and removed on this site. This site is hostile to truth, I realize that now. You have not been hostile in your delivery, but if the truth is not welcome here, neither am I.

Comment: @JeremySt.Germain, this site is not hostile to truth, it is simply unconcerned with religious truth. Questions should be about the intended meaning of specific scripture, and scholarly methods by which that meaning can be deduced. It is not about whether those meanings are actually true in a religious sense. If an answer isn't worded in a way that can also be accepted by non-Christians, it isn't appropriate here. ¶ Thomas Farrar's answer for instance cites specific ancient documents that indicate what the author was likely thinking. Even an Atheist can accept that as a good answer.

Comment: @RayButterworth, Truth is truth, religious or otherwise. To comply with this site’s requirements is to leave many of the questions on this site unanswered. The truth sought by those who ask is not always something that can be arrived at by scholarly means. Truth is divine, and He is alive. Atheists and non Christian’s tend to be unconcerned with Truth, thus hostile to it because the Truth will not be ignored. I give truth, as I’m given truth, and I’m unconcerned whether an atheist or non Christian can or will accept it as a good answer. Respectfully.

Comment: There are some requirements that make it difficult for those who believe in divine truth to engage with this site, especially in selecting questions to answer, but there still are opportunities. This link demonstrates the problem, with one answer that hits the nail on the head by a user. I'm sure you will identify and empathise with him. One point of the rules is to stop unseemly arguing, especially in comments. https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/can-we-please-just-ban-scoping-to-trinitarians-and-anti-trinitarians/7384#7384

Comment: @Anne, Well that was spot on.  Maybe I should spend a little more time in the christianity SE vs the biblical SE. I’m painfully aware of the challenges on this site, thank you for helping me see the opportunities.

Comment: Love this! I can feel the wisdom! Just make sure to ask for which scriptures back this up!

Answer (score -1):

I would also like to add that Jesus was not forsaken ever by the Father nor will ever forsake any believers as His word says. No word will come from the Lords mouth and return to him empty or void. This is clear in Psalm 22 where David was giving the rest of Jesus speech on the cross. The Father gave Jesus everything ultimately. Lastly the Father gave us everything through the death and resurrection of His Son Jesus Christ.

Comment: Please read the section on what we look for in well researched answers:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).